# undefined method `get' for #<RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

**My Test Spec**

```
it "can find an account" do 
    get "/account/#{@acc.id}", {}, {"Accept" => "application/json"}
  end
```

I get the below error when i try to run my rspec.

```
Failure/Error: get "/account/#{@acc.id}", {}, {"Accept" => "application/json"}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Account_2:0x00000004a6d430>
```

And also how can i pass another `params authorization` to my get method as i pass in find method.

```
Account.find(id: @acc.id, authorization: @token);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `get` is only available when testing controller. With new rspec you need to tell explicitly what you are testing with:

```
describe MyController, type: :controller do
```

Comment: Inside my it block... can i print anything... i mean something like console.log in js

Comment: Can you tell me on what's wrong with my class... i have updated the code. coz i get name is undefined.

Comment: @user3918045 - It is way to little code to say. Could you please paste the whole file?

Comment: @UnderTaker You can add `gem 'pry'` in Gemfile. Then on top of the file, add `require 'pry'` and you can add `binding.pry` wherever you want to debug / puts. On terminal, you can use any ruby method or call any method from your project. It's your console. Use `exit` to complete the execution. After debugging remove `binding.pry`